# does order by in view object work for unsaved row in ADF?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c, oracle-adf

I have to apply some validations in before save method in managed bean.For that the currently entering row is to be sorted and checked with row just near it in sorted order. Is this possible?

Comment: i am using order by in VO to sort them.Now all rows except unsaved row comes in sorted order

Answer (score 0):

The sort operation is operating in the database - so if you didn't save your new record it will not be there for the sort operation.